# From which year do T-101 and T-1000 come from?

Tags: plot-explanation, terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

In the movie Terminator 2, is there any mention of which year the two machines T-101 and T-1000 come from? The first movie specifies 2029. Does this movie specify a year?

Comment: It's not T-101, 101 is a model no of T-800.

Comment: T-800 is a model number too right? I assumed it's synonymous to T101. (sort of like Java 1.5 and Java 5?)

Comment: In Terminator 2: Judgment Day, it is shown CSM-101 T-800 Version 2.4 , i think its kind of colur of a phone. Maybe 102 looks like Angelina Jolie.

Comment: See also: [From which years are the Terminators sent back?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/36348/1876)

Answer (score 4):

The movie doesn't say, but the official [Randall Frakes novelisation](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Terminator_2:_Judgment_Day_(Frakes_novel)) indicates that Skynet was "smashed" in the second timeline some time after John's 45th birthday.

> Sadly, he lowered the binoculars, **revealing forty-five-year-old
>   features made severe by constant stress.** The left side of his face was
>   heavily scarred. Yet he was still an impressive man, forged in the
>   furnace of a lifetime of war. The name stitched on his jacket read
>   CONNOR.

Since the events of  T2 took place in June 1992 when John was 10 years old, we can calculate that the T-1000 and reprogrammed T-800 **were from the year 2027**, two full years *before* the date that the original Terminator (and Kyle Reese) were dispatched into the past in the first timeline seen in the original Terminator movie.

Comment: Actually no, the movie T2 was made in in 1991 but the events of the movie are set in 1995. Using your info, that would add 3 years and hence 2030. 2030 makes sense and 2027 doesn't because the machines would need time to advance their Terminator machines from T101 to T1000. No event from part 1 delays judgement day, in fact it T101 from part 1 ensures the creation of Skynet itself. Your answer helps with the date changed to 2030. Thanks.

Comment: @tivep - Note that various iterations of Skynet are more advanced due to its inteference in its own timeline. The initial Skynet was a single mainframe, later versions are distributed systems, etc. It's easily possible for it to send off a more advanced T-1000 from 2027.

Comment: That is true @Richard, the iterations change Skynet but the iterations always have been shown to delay Judgement Day and hence delay in the birth of Skynet. Part 1 and 2 share the same judgement day. This is because the T101 from part 1 is the thing that humans use to come up with Skynet (this is shown in part 2). Hence there would be no iteration on the birth of Skynet in this case. In any case, when John was 10 it was the year 1995. So 1995 + 35 would take us to the year 2030.

Comment: @Tivep - They may delay judgement day, but Skynet keeps getting smarter (and more advanced) quicker each time he goes live. (Noting that in the deleted scene at the end of T2, judgement day doesn't happen at all).

Comment: good point. Looks like there is actually a dialogue in the movie talking about the year T-101 comes from.

Answer (score 1):

See this trailer for Judgement Day:

Go to position 1:00. Terminator actually tells John Connor that he was sent 35 years from today. It's there in the movie:

> "You did.  Thirty years from now you reprogrammed me to be your
>   protector here, in this time."

T2 happens in 1995. So plus 35 is 2030.

Comment: Accepting this one even though the answer is the same as Richard's, because this is an in-movie based answer.