# From which years are the Terminators sent back?

Tags: the-terminator, terminator-2-judgment-day, terminator-3-rise-of-the-machines, terminator-series

From which years in the future are the terminators in Terminator 1, 2 and 3 sent back?

Comment: See also: [From which year do T-101 and T-1000 come from?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/36220/1876)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Terminator 1: 2029 to 1984

Terminator 2: 2029 to 1994/95

There is slight confusion in year Terminator 2 takes place in, Per [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103064/faq#.2.1.24):

> The first Terminator film takes place in May 1984. According to
>   information provided at the beginning of the movie, it is now 1995,
>   since John was born on 28 February 1985 and is currently 10 years old.
>   If that's the case, it contradicts the T-800's claim that it was sent
>   back 35 years in time (from 2029), which would place the film in 1994.
>   Another contradiction is when The Terminator states "in three years
>   Cyberdyne will..." which indicates the film takes place three years
>   before Judgement Day (which occurs in 1997), again making it 1994.

Terminator 3: 2032 to 2004

Following is graphical representation from [Terminator wiki](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Terminator_3:_Rise_of_the_Machines_timeline)

[image]